# Reveal text letter by letter but retain html formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I need my text to retain a few html formatting tags, to change the colour of the text as it goes along for example and to show some graphic icons that are placed in my text. My code takes the text from an existing hidden paragraph, blanks the paragraph, unhides it and then reveals it letter by letter as follows.

```
        var NextHighlight = HighlightsTop.find('.newhidden').first().closest('p'); // Find the paragraph.
        // Put the text from this highlight paragraph into a variable and remove it from the paragraph, so that we can put it back letter-by-letter below.
        var HighlightText = NextHighlight.html();
        NextHighlight.html("");
        NextHighlight.removeClass('newhidden');

        // Add the text back in, letter by letter.
        showText(NextHighlight, HighlightText, 0, 5);    

....

    // The letter-by-letter function.
    var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {    
    if (index < message.length) { 
        $(target).append(message[index++]); 
        setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
        } 
    }
```

The problem is that the html tags are now just shown as straight text in the line. If I change 'html' to 'text' in the elements, it doesn't show the tags but I don't get the formatting either.

EDIT - UPDATE below....

After updating with the answer below, my code now looks like this. I should point out that this happens when the user hits a button, so I'm adding the code from the start of the button click. Maybe there's an error somewhere that I can't see because when I click the button now, I get nothing at all. I'm not seeing any errors in the console either, wondering if I've just missed a ; somewhere...

```
$(document).on('click', '.highlight_button',
    function () {
        var MatchReportTop = $(this).closest('.match_div'); 
        var HighlightsTop = $(this).closest('.highlights');
        var NextHighlight = $('.newhidden').first().closest('p'), HighlightTextNodes = [];

        // recursively get the text nodes
        (function recursiveGetTextNodes(node) {
          if(node.nodeType === 3) {
            // we're a text node? great, store it.  We'll store a clone and the original so we don't lose our place.
            HighlightTextNodes.push({
              active: node,
              ref: node.cloneNode()
            });
            // clear out the original.
            node.textContent = '';
          } else {
            // no text node.  go deeper.
            for(var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
              recursiveGetTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
          }
        })(NextHighlight.get(0))

        // Add the text back in, letter by letter.
        showText(HighlightTextNodes, 5);

        if (NextHighlight.hasClass('FullTime')) {
            CompleteReveal(MatchReportTop);
        }
}); 

// The letter-by-letter function.
function showText(target, interval) {
  // to know what we're currently working on, we need to filter
  // the text nodes by a check to see if they are already fully
  // "typed" out.  If the content doesn't match, keep it.  Also,
  // `shift()` off the first one.  That's the one we'll edit
  // this go around.
  var current = target.filter(function(a){
    return a.active.textContent != a.ref.textContent;
  }).shift();

  // if we have a node to work with, the process is not
  // completed. Once `current` is false, we know we've completed
  // the process.
  if (current) { 
    // grab the reference node's text up to the active node's
    // length +1 to get the current text plus one letter.
    current.active.textContent = current.ref.textContent.substr(0,current.active.textContent.length + 1);
    // rinse and repeat.
    setTimeout(function () {
      showText(target, interval);
    }, interval); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see a small portion of the markup?  I'm not quite understanding where `.highlight_button`, `.match_div`, `.highlights`, etc. fall in the layout.

Comment: Here's an example of the markup, although right now, I don't think that's the problem because when I hit the button, nothing at all is happening. It's reacting as if there's an error and it's just stopping. Anyway, this is an example of a line....

2:01  -  Stephen Rinkert deftly skips past Ray Whaley and strikes a shot at goal from inside the box. Caleb Heydon dives across but can't reach it and it flies into the roof of the net. <span class="goalfont">GOAL!</span> <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i> <span class="scoreline">Accrington Wanderers 0 : 1 Aylesford Athletic</span>

Comment: .highlight_button is the class of the button itself. .match_div is just a div containing the many lines of text. What I'm doing is, each time the user hits a button, another line of the text appears. I could give you a link/pass to the game itself so you could possibly look at it in action and maybe follow it through in the console.

But I still think something is wrong with the code because of way it's just doing nothing at all (e.g I think I've missed a ; or a bracket somewhere).

Comment: Oh ok, I found it, it's because I just copied your code and you'd removed the 'removeclass' part. I added it back and it's working fine. It's actually come up with an interesting little side-effect which is good, if the final letter is the graphic-football (which I use to indicate a goal), that sort of rolls along as it prints. Total bonus. Thanks for your help, marked your answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: lol.  Sorry about that.  I removed that snippet to simplify the important parts.  Glad it's working.

Comment: I don't know if adding new comments a couple of months later is a good idea or if they'll be seen. I want to make some changes to this so that the code now reveals over all lines (i.e when it's finished with line 1, it'll start printing line 2) and have two or more buttons to alter the speed of the reveal. If I don't get replies here, I guess I'll need to rebuild the whole question from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to incrementally show text, but it has to retain the HTML.  You could strip the tags and reapply them.  You could ignore the tags as you parse the text and just paste them in in their entirety.  Those are a couple options that first came to mind, but I kind of dislike both of them.

If you rethink the problem, there might be a better solution.  You could target text nodes only and incrementally display each letter from those text nodes.  This is the plan I settled on after rethinking it.  The basic flow would be this:

1. Gather the text nodes, store their original nodes (that are still attached to the DOM)
2. store a clone of the node for reference later
3. empty out the text node
4. recursively call a timed method that looks for the first node that doesn't match the reference node
5. add a single letter to that node from the reference node
6. repeat until all nodes match the reference nodes

```js
// get the `newhidden`'s closest parent paragraph and prepare
// the array that will hold all the text nodes of that paragraph
var NextHighlight = $('.newhidden').first().closest('p'), HighlightTextNodes = [];

// recursively get the text nodes
(function recursiveGetTextNodes(node) {
  if(node.nodeType === 3) {
    // we're a text node? great, store it.  We'll store a clone
    // and the original so we don't lose our place.
    HighlightTextNodes.push({
      active: node,
      ref: node.cloneNode()
    });
    // clear out the original.
    node.textContent = '';
  } else {
    // no text node.  go deeper.
    for(var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
      recursiveGetTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
})(NextHighlight.get(0))

// Add the text back in, letter by letter.
showText(HighlightTextNodes, 5);

// The letter-by-letter function.
function showText(target, interval) {
  // to know what we're currently working on, we need to filter
  // the text nodes by a check to see if they are already fully
  // "typed" out.  If the content doesn't match, keep it.  Also,
  // `shift()` off the first one.  That's the one we'll edit
  // this go around.
  var current = target.filter(function(a){
    return a.active.textContent != a.ref.textContent;
  }).shift();
  
  // if we have a node to work with, the process is not
  // completed. Once `current` is falsy, we know we've completed
  // the process.
  if (current) { 
    // grab the reference node's text up to the active node's
    // length +1 to get the current text plus one letter.
    current.active.textContent = current.ref.textContent.substr(0,current.active.textContent.length + 1);
    // rinse and repeat.
    setTimeout(function () {
      showText(target, interval);
    }, interval); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, impedit <strong class="newhidden">labore <span>test</span> architecto</strong> quasi, possimus hic velit. Quibusdam quisquam illum quae doloremque, quis iste consequatur vero quaerat molestias doloribus dicta facilis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas iusto laborum hic optio aliquam, adipisci a, dolore rem dolores harum voluptas cum! Similique, velit, commodi. Vero molestias, nobis ducimus nemo.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort on this one. I don't have room to cut and paste my new code, so I'll edit the original to see if you can spot any errors, because it's not running at all at my end. I may have made an error somewhere that I can't spot, or maybe something else is wrong. I'll try to put more details in the original.

Comment: @Farflame I'll be happy to take a look.  You can also use services like jsfiddle.net to build more extensive examples.  I find it pretty useful for longer blocks of example code.

Comment: If you pick up this reply, two months later, do you know if it'd be possible to have it reveal all lines? i.e Reveal line one as above, then move straight on to line 2 until all lines are complete? And I'd need buttons to speed up or slow down the speed of the reveal (including slowing it down to a stop).

Comment: @Farflame  Yeah, I see when a comment is posted to one of my answers (it emails me).  The speed thing would be really easy to add, but I'll have to look at it closer later today to figure out the first part of your question.  Feel free to post another question too.  I'll revisit this answer tonight, but you might get a quicker response by posting a new one. Make sure to link to your first one to give any new developers the context of your new question.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that you could take a look since you made the code above and it works as intended. If it's just a few changes to that, hopefully you can help me out. If not, I can of course re-post the entire thing, but I'll wait for your reply first to see if it's a simple addition to the above or requires any kind of re-work.